# Slide up and down bottom Menu CSS

Tags: html, css, jscript

I am having trouble finding a solution to something that I want to do. Any tutorial I find does too much or is too complicated.

What I want to make a slide up bottom menu that has some text when it is down, if you click the text/link the css ID will change and it will appear. I am just starting to delve into the world of dynamic web pages.

**HTML**

```
<div id="foot"> <font color="white">Down</font>
```

**CSS**

```
#foot {
position: fixed;
bottom:0px;
width: 99.1%;
height: 30%;
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
}
\/ When the menu is down
#footdown {
position: fixed;
bottom:0px;
width: 99.1%;
height: 4%;
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7pc786a/

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/w7pc786a/1/

Comment: Holy horse in the back yard, I am so stupid!